# Table view cell like Notes App

Tags: ios, uitableview

Through my searching, I have been unable to find my answer.

Basically I have a basic notes like view controller. I want the effect like notes where the first line is the Title of the note and the rest of the body is in the subtitle trailing off.

How I have it set up:

```
NSString *note = nil;
if (tableView == self.tableView) {
    note = [noteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
NSString *date = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSInteger charnum = [note length];
if (charnum >= 22) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[note substringToIndex:18] stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
}
else{
    cell.textLabel.text = note;
}

[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", date, [note substringFromIndex:18]]];
[cell.detailTextLabel setNumberOfLines:1];
```

Right now it reads to the 18 characters and then ... and the subtitle picks it up for the rest.

How would I set up the Title/Header and then the body for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. In case anybody is interested here is how I did it.

It was a combination of setting it properly in the textView like so:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.textView.text];
    [newString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    NSString *trimmed = [newString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    NSRange newLineRange = [trimmed rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    if(newLineRange.length > 0)
    {
        self.textView.text = [trimmed substringToIndex:newLineRange.location];
    }
    else {
        self.textView.text = trimmed;
    }

    return YES;

}
```

Which saves the first line as the "title"

Next in my tableView, I set the display as below: (I'm going to provide my whole cell call instead of the stuff I changed).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault];
    [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:1];
    [cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode : NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
    [cell setClipsToBounds:YES];

    // Configure the cell label.
    [cell.textLabel setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];

    //Cell Base color
    [cell.contentView.superview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.271 green:0.271 blue:0.271 alpha:1]];

    //Cell selection color
    UIView *cellColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [cellColor setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.176 green:0.176 blue:0.176 alpha:0.95]];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:cellColor];

    //Cell border
    [cell.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:30/255.0 green:30/255.0 blue:30/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
    [cell.layer setBorderWidth:1.5f];

    //Setting the first line of cell.
    NSString *note = nil;
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        note = [noteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = note;

    //Subtitle line.
    NSRange startRange = NSMakeRange(1, 0);
    NSRange titleRange = [note lineRangeForRange:startRange];
    NSString *titleString = [note substringFromIndex:titleRange.length];
    titleString = [titleString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    //titleString = [titleString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@""];

    //Setting the date.
    NSString *date = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.detailTextLabel setNumberOfLines:1];

    //New method of having two seperate colors for the detail string.
    NSAttributedString *scoreAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:date attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.20 green:0.67 blue:0.86 alpha:1.0]}];
    NSAttributedString *domainAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:titleString attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightTextColor]}];

    NSMutableAttributedString *detailMutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    [detailMutableAttributedString appendAttributedString:scoreAttributedString];
    [detailMutableAttributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" "]];
    [detailMutableAttributedString appendAttributedString:domainAttributedString];

    [[cell detailTextLabel] setAttributedText:detailMutableAttributedString];  
}
```

Hope this helps somebody.